# Is it possible to vertically rotate a showwaves (or showfreqs) overlay using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, command-line, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I wish to take a `showwaves` (or `showfreqs`) overlay and center it vertically using ffmpeg, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=scroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080,pad=1920:1080[vs]; [0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=rscroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080[ss]; [0:a]showwaves=s=1920x540:colors=B80000|950000|690000:mode=p2p,inflate[sw]; [vs][ss]overlay=w[out]; [out][sw]overlay=0:(H-h)/2[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

[image]

As shown above, the `showwaves` output is centered horizontally. But would it also be possible to have it centered vertically? Specifically, using a single `-filter_complex` command argument?

I've looked through the ffmpeg manual and searched stackoverflow for an answer, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the transpose filter.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=scroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080,pad=1920:1080[vs]; [0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=rscroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080[ss]; [0:a]showwaves=s=1080x540:colors=B80000|950000|690000:mode=p2p,inflate,transpose=cclock[sw]; [vs][ss]overlay=w[out]; [out][sw]overlay=(W-w)/2:0[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv`